# Get firebase key after push ( python2.7 )

Tags: python, python-2.7, firebase-realtime-database, callback, key

I am using Python 2.7 and Pyrebase(as a package to communicate with my Firebase database).
I am trying to get the `key()` of the newly pushed object in my database. I did this a lot of times with node.js, but I need some help to do it with Python 2.7
Here is my API:

```
@APP.route('/api/product', methods = ['POST'])
def products():
    product_details = {
        "title": request.form['title'],
        "description": request.form['description']
    }
    new_product = DB.push("product").push(product_details)
    print new_product.get().key()

    return json.dumps(apiResponse.success(product_details))
```

The object will be inserted into the database, but I have no idea how to get its key.
In node.js, I would use a promise and after insertion, I will get the key.

P.S: I cannot use `.ref()` since I use `Pyrebase` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this to my code:
 `rec = DB.child("product").push(product_details)` and this way, I was able to get the key.So, my code looks like this now:

```
@APP.route('/api/product', methods = ['POST'])
def products():
    product_details = {
        "title": request.form['title'],
        "description": request.form['description']
    }
  DB.child("product").push(product_details)
  rec = DB.child("product").push(product_details)   
  DB.child("users").child(owner_details['uid']).child('products').update({rec['name']: "true"})
  return json.dumps(apiResponse.success(product_details))
```